# Android setRotation on marker hiding marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to move and rotate marker as per direction, move marker is working perfectly but when I adding marker rotation it hide marker, I am using following code for marker move animation and rotation when I comment `setRotation()` method it work perfectly but when i uncomment `setRotation()` line it hide marker on location update

```
public void animateMarker(final LatLng toPosition,final LatLng neLatLong,
                          final boolean hideMarker) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final long duration = 200;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);
            curMarker.setPosition(toPosition);
            curMarker.setRotation(getBearing(toPosition,neLatLong));

            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    curMarker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    curMarker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

    if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
    else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)` set for your marker and better use [`SphericalUtil.computeHeading()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeHeading-LatLng-LatLng-) from [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/)  instead of your `private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end)`